# python datatype coversion behaves different in print and write

Tags: python

Code snippet as below, (I'd like to store whole dict content if some key is not in the dict, else only store the key's value)

```
result = {
    'stdout': 'some output'
}

print('result: %s' % result['stderr'] if 'stderr' in result else result)

with open('result.txt', 'w') as f:
    f.write('result: %s\n' % result['stderr'] if 'stderr' in result else result)
```

here I tried to log some message use `write`, which check if `stderr` in a dict `result`, if yes then use it(a string), else log the dict `result`.

In `print` it work fine, but failed in `write`:

> TypeError: write() argument must be str, not dict

because I use `%s` which I expect either string or dict will be automatically converted to string? (i.e `str(result)`)

Why it failed on `write`?

Comment: `f.write('result: %s\n' % output['stderr'] if 'stderr' in output else "")` ?

Comment: if there is no `stderr`, I'd like to save the whole str(result)

Comment: despite the bracket confusion pointed out by @mikhail-burshteyn, just use `f.write('result: {}\n'.format( result['stdout'] if 'stdout' in result else result ) )` avoiding the problem in the first place.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The problem in your code is that '%' has higher precedence than the conditional operator. Because of this,

```
'result: %s' % result['stderr'] if 'stderr' in result else result
```

is equivalent to

```
('result: %s' % result['stderr']) if 'stderr' in result else result
```

So, if `'stderr' not in result`, this expression will return `result`, which is a dict.  Now, `print()` will print anything, but `write` needs a string argument and fails when receives a dict.

The result you want is:

```
'result: %s' % (result['stderr'] if 'stderr' in result else result)
```

Your code should be modified as follows:

```
print('result: %s' % (result['stderr'] if 'stderr' in result else result))

with open('result.txt', 'w') as f:
    f.write('result: %s\n' % (result['stderr'] if 'stderr' in result else result))
```

Answer (score 2):

You see the error because the Python expression that you have will result in a dictionary object if 'result' doesn't contain 'stdout'. This can be `print`-ed - print happily accepts any data type, but write does not.

The problem is with the priority of operations in your expression: if ... else binds less tightly than %.

I suspect that what you wanted is this:

```
f.write('result: %s\n' % (result['stderr'] if 'stderr' in result else result) )
```

NOTE the parentheses.